# How to create a time slider using arcgis javascript that only shows a year at a time?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, time

I am looking at [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer.html) example on how to create a time slider using the arcgis javascript api. Instead of showing the data cumulative from the start date. I want to just show the data for that particular year. I have tried changing the ThumbCount to 1, but all that does is set the start time to the start time. Other than that, I can't seem to find any more information on how to get the behavior that I want.

I understand that I can use 2 thumbs on the time slider in order to get desired result. However, I am looking to see if it is possible by using only 1 thumb slider.

Answer (score 1):

I must've missed it in the APi documentation. There is a function called `singleThumbAsTimeInstant(createTimeInstants)` for the time slider. Once you set this to true, then it will only display items at that specific time. The documentation is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/timeslider-amd.html).